# How to use radiobuttons to modify the columns of Gridview in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I have a gridview(admin.php) of test table. Here, I have two colums Contact Approval and Greetings Approval. I need to put two radio buttons ('Contact' and 'Greetings')in admin page. When I click on 'Contact' radio button all the columns except for Greetings Approval should be displayed in gridview and When I click on 'Greetings' radio button all the columns except for Contact Approval should be displayed in gridview. The update.php should also have the same effect.i.e when I click on edit option the update.php should have the fields based on the radiobutton data.How can I do this.
[image]

Below is the code of radiobuttonlist

```
    <div class="ContactGreetingGroup">        
<?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList('approval','',array('0'=>'Greetings Approval','1'=>'Contact Approval'),array(
    'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
    'onclick' => 'this.form.submit()', 
    'separator'=>''));     
?>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CDataColumn has a 'visible' property. You just need to set it depending on your parameter.

```
$approval = Yii::app()->request->getParam('approval');

'columns'=>[
    [
       'name'    => 'greetings',
       'visible' => ($approval)? false : true,
    ],
    [
       'name'    => 'contact',
       'visible' => ($approval)? true : false,
    ],
],
```

As for changing the behavior of the edit button, (since you need a parameter to say if you want "contact-mode" or "greetings-mode") You must overwrite the view-buttons url property.

```
[
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'buttons'=>[
        'view' => [
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(
                "Something/Update", 
                ["id"=>$data->id, "approval"->$approval ])',
        ],
    ],
],
```

After that you need to make a similar check in your update.php (_form.php) to decide what to display.

```
if( $approval ) :
....
```

---

### Added:

If your radiobuttonlist is inside form-tags, you can submit it like this:

```
<form>  <!-- You need a form to use form.submit! -->
    <?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList('approval','',
        array('0'=>'Greetings Approval','1'=>'Contact Approval'),
        array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
        'onclick' => 'this.form.submit()',   // Added this.
        'separator'=>'')
); ?>
</form>
```

I also edited the above code to match your variable names. I haven't tested it, but it should give you an idea I hope.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply...I used radiobuttonlist. Please tell me what should I do for this.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do it with above attached radiobuttonlist code.

Comment: This isn't working for radiobuttonlist done with the above code

Comment: There is no action of radiobutton at all

Comment: did you add the onclick? It MUST be inside <form> tags to be submitted as a form. If you don't want the page-refresh, you should render it all inside a renderPartial but you ought to leave that for another question.

Comment: Yes...I got it.Now the radiobutton is working but it goes to a different page. Url-http://localhost/yii/test/index.php?approval=1. Nothing gets displayed

Comment: Hello ippi, pls guide me on this

Comment: <form action="some/url/page.html"> controls where you are sent. Leaving it blank *should* return you to the same page. Maybe you have nested forms causing you end up somewhere else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35253/discussion-between-ippi-and-rudra)